# Error after (seemingly) following the Heroku instructions for Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

**ANSWER:** Don't put a Gemfile into the root of your Node.js project. Heroku get's confused and treats it like a Ruby app.

I am trying to follow the instructions from the Heroku documentation but am receiving an error: "No such file or directory - node web.js".

My Procfile is...

```
web: node web.js
```

Foreman runs locally as expected.

Here's a logging snapshot...

```
2011-07-21T23:28:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed 
2011-07-21T23:37:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created 
2011-07-21T23:37:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting 
2011-07-21T23:37:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `node web.js` 
2011-07-21T23:37:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No such file or directory - node web.js 
2011-07-21T23:37:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

And my heroku ps output...

```
Process State Command 
------------ ------------------ ------------------------------ 
web.1 crashed for 8m node web.js
```

Source is https://github.com/just3ws/hellode

If it didn't run locally I'd move forward and just assume it was only me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May want to check out my getting started guide and see if you missed something:  http://www.jamesward.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-node-js-on-the-cloud/

Comment: @James thanks, I went through and reviewed your post. Everything seems to be in order on my site. The only thing I haven't done is rename the Heroku app. I'm feeling that this might actually be a problem on Heroku's side but am willing to accept it may be PEBKAC.

Comment: Did you create the app with the "cedar" stack?

Comment: @James yep. but just worked through the issue with a friend. Turns out that the Gemfile I'd checked into the project was causing some confusion on Heroku's side.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Sorry I wasn't more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it's the Gemfile or .rvmrc ;)

http://twitter.com/ryanbriones/status/94212379654631424

Comment: What was the problem exactly?

Comment: There was a Gemfile in the root of the project directory so heroku thought it was a ruby application and failed to execute it.